# What is good font-sizing method for mobile sites?

Tags: css, mobile, windows-mobile, mobile-website, mobile-phones

Is this still a best solution for mobile? specially for older mobiles?

```
body { font-size: 62.5%;  /* 16px × 62.5% = 10px */ }
h1 { font-size: 2em; /* 10px × 2em = 20px */ }
p { font-size: 1.2em; /* 10px × 1.2em = 12px */ }
```

Comment: Why can't you use pixel-based fonts? And what do you mean by **best**?

Comment: I get this error in Mobile OK checker "Using absolute measures in CSS creates layouts that do not adapt to the screen dimensions."

Answer (score 1):

I personally use

font-size: large

font-size: medium

font-size: small

and assume device will adjust the size according to it's screen. Usually works fine.

May I ask why are you trying to get css validated?

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer. It's not CSS validator it's a Mobile compatibility checker. "Using absolute measures in CSS creates layouts that do not adapt to the screen dimensions."

Answer (score 0):

Good question :), wondered the same myself but not found a good article or tutorial yet.

Some things to consider when choosing what's "best" for your situation:

- em is a friendly unit as it scales with the base font size a user may choose
- dpi-independent resolutions like mm or cm can give you some control to make things "readable"
- beware that not all mobile browsers may support all unit types (specially since you mentioned wanting to support older mobiles)